# Targeting phones with media queries

Tags: media-queries

I know this type of question has been asked before, I've read the answers and still cannot get this to work. I have the following breakpoint:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*css*/
}
```

is this not saying "apply these styles to screens 600px and less" ? Or am I misinterpreting the use of `max-width`? When I drag my browser to <600px I can see the styles take effect, but when I view the site on an iPhone the styles applied at this breakpoint are not shown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, and your media query should indeed target iPhones. It's possible that you have cached the old CSS on the iPhone, however.

Comment: I had to change `max-width` to `max-device-width` ... not sure why but this worked.